# Azure ARM Deployment slot - adding application settings

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

When I read the doc for both slot and site,

1. Website: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2018-02-01/sites
2. Deployment slot: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2018-11-01/sites/slots

I can see that I can apply application settings by adding to properties.siteconfig.appsettings to either the website or a slot. This I how I do it today for the website, but I am wondering if, even though the deployment slot has the same structure, if I can add settings to my slot by doing the same? I don't care about sticky settings. The reason why I am asking is that when I export from the portal I can't see how they do it and everywhere I look on the Internet people is using the Microsoft.Web/sites/config type or Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/config type. Can't i just use properties.siteconfig.appsettings as in the doc for the deploy slot, or am I missing something fundamental?

I am not in a position where I can go to a computer and test it, but my mind is going nuts to find out.

Comment: why would it have the other structure, its the same entity (deployment slot) just called differently, no?

Comment: @4c74356b41 well good question, but when I Google it all others is referring to a resource type called "Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/config" and "Microsoft.web/sites/config". I have never used those to config my sites with so I am just curious if I am missing something. In my head I should just be able to fill out properties.siteconfig.appsettings for the slots, because, as I understand, when you have no slots and deploy, you actually deploy to the production slot, which is nameless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could indeed configure the appsettings through the `siteconfig` tag. As for your puzzle, it's because you don't understand why there are two ways to set the appsettings.

Actually the `siteconfig` is used to [Prevent copying settings from the Prod site](https://github.com/ggirard07/ARMSlotWebConfig/pull/1/files), you could check the github pull.

Hope this could help you.

Comment: So just to be clear, I can configure the slot with the siteconfig? I only use it to warm up before switching so there will always be a 1 to 1 between the staging and production slot.

Comment: Aaaah. If I add the siteconfig with appsettings on the slot it doesn't copy the production slot settings when the slot is created the first time?

Comment: From this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50052106/10383250) and the github description, yes it is.

Comment: Thanks. I will presume that it is possible to configure a slot with the siteconfig and it will update when I add settings to it and redeploy the arm. Sorry for being so pedantic but I have had many experiences with ARM where I thought I knew how it worked but I was surprised to find out otherwise.